# Regex to capture parenthesis with hash tag?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

So far I have this perfectly working regex:

```
(?:(?<=\s)|^)#(\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*)
```

It finds any word that starts with a hash tag (ex. `#lolz` but not hsshs#jdjd)

The problem is I also want it to match parenthesis.  So if I have this it will match:

`(#lolz` wow)

or
(wow `#cool)`

or
`(#cool)`

Any idea on how can I make or use my regex to work like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seemed to work for me ...

```
\(?#(\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*)\)?
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you are using the following in context is overkill..

```
\w*[A-Za-z_]\w*
```

`\w` alone **matches** word characters ( `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` ). And it is not necessary for the use of the non-capturing group `(?:` to be wrapped around your lookbehind assertion here.

I do believe that the following would suffice by itself.

```
(?<=^|\s)\(?#(\w+)\)?
```

Regular expression:

```
(?<=         look behind to see if there is:
 ^           the beginning of the string
 |           OR
  \s         whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") 
)            end of look-behind
\(?          '(' (optional (matching the most amount possible))
 #           '#'
  (          group and capture to \1:
   \w+       word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times)
  )          end of \1
 \)?         ')' (optional (matching the most amount possible))
```

See [`live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/tG4gC3)

You can also use a negative lookbehind here if you wanted to.

```
(?<![^\s])\(?#(\w+)\)?
```